# How to send job notifications with dbms_scheduler via ssl encrypted smtp

Tags: oracle, wallet, jobs

We have Oracle Enterprise 19 Databases installed on Linux and using job notification via smtp with **Oracle dbms_scheduler** for quite a long time. Defining jobs like this and having all the needed settings like SMTP server, ports etc defined in dbms_scheduler attributes:

```
dbms_scheduler.add_job_email_notification(
  job_name   =>  'J1',
  recipients =>  'jobowner@example.com',
  events     =>  'job_all_events');
```

That worked fine.

Now for obvious reasons our mail environment got encrypted and we need to use SSL to communicate with the SMTP server. A certificate is required and placed into a wallet. We did that using orapki and put the wallet in the filesystem location documented by Oracle $ORACLE_HOME/scheduler/wallet/

```
orapki wallet create -wallet /orasoft/oracle/product/19.0.0/world/scheduler/wallet/5 -pwd password -auto_login
orapki wallet add -wallet /orasoft/oracle/product/19.0.0/world/scheduler/wallet/5 -trusted_cert -cert ~/MailRootCA.cer
```

Inside the DB we changed dbms_scheduler settings accordingly:

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_SCHEDULER_ATTRIBUTE (
attribute => 'EMAIL_SERVER_ENCRYPTION',
value => 'STARTTLS');  --thats what our mailserver expects
```

Added the correct ports to host ace's and also a wallet ace:

```
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.append_WALLET_ACE(
  wallet_path => 'file:/orasoft/oracle/product/19.0.0/world/scheduler/wallet/5/',
  ace     => xs$ace_type(
           privilege_list => xs$name_list('use_client_certificates', 'use_passwords'),
           principal_name => 'SYS',
           principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db
          )
```

But somehow it is not working anymore. A trace file is generated each time a mail should be sent with

`ORA-29106: Cannot import PKCS #12 wallet.`

Has anyone else encountered this issue? And how to get around it?

Thanks.

Comment: You set a password on the wallet: are you sure you pass it everywhere it's needed?
(not seen in your "add" of the root certificate... and btw: no intermediate certificate?)
And fyi, there was an old bug in okapi of <12c versions, not supporting some "special" characters ($ and the likes) in the password.

Comment: @p3consulting Yes, password on the wallet is fine. It is asked interactively with the "add" command. It is only as special as it has to be. So only alphanumeric. And we are using version 19. I can also display the wallet content without problems. I tried adding all subCA certificates as well, no difference.